# Xamarin.Forms Debugger not working in VS 2015 since update to latest stable Xamarin SDK

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Today I updated to the latest "stable" Xamarin SDK Version [4.5.0.443 (c871575)] in VS2015 Enterprise [Update 3] and now when I start my Xamarin.Forms Android App in Debug mode (F5) on a real device my breakpoints are **not hit any more.**

I have VS 2017 Enterprise installed on the same development machine, too.

Comment: I had the same issue with Xamarin Studio on Mac, the weird thing is that the debugger is working on Visual Studio for Mac. So I am now using Visual Studio, my guess is that you should try using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Same on VS 2017. Breakpoints ain't not hitvanymore.,Thanks for yor reply

Comment: FWIW, there's already a newer version out (4.5.0.475)

Comment: @samgak Thank you so much. After update to v.4.5.0.475 in VS2015 debugging ist working again ! In VS2017 it is still not working but in the release notes there is a vague hint https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.5/#bugfixes

Answer (score 0):

As @samgak suggested the update to v.4.5.0.475 in VS2015 solved that issue, Update to that version in VS2015 in the Xamarin "stable" channel.